# How to render specific form elements Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I am using Drupal 8 and would like to customize how form elements are being displayed. Specifically, I don't like how uneditable, populated textfields are displayed as plain text. I would have it being displayed as an editable textfield (or have the text look like it is in an uneditable textfield). I have looked at various hook functions to try and achieve this but nothing seems to work.

I figure the best way to go about this is if I can render the form fields individually myself and then create a twig file that displays the individual fields as I would like them to be displayed. Here is what I would like the twig field to look like:

```html
<div class="from">
  {{ form.mail }}
</div>

<div class="message">
  {{ form.message }}
</div>

<div class="actions">
  {{ form.actions }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .module file

```
function your_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return [
        'custom_theme' => [
            'variables' => [
                'form' => NULL
            ],
            'render element' => 'form',
        ]
    ];
}
```

In your CustomForm.php file

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    [...your fields ...]
    return $form
}
```

In your custom module templates directory

custom-theme.html.twig

```
{{ form.your_field }}
```